# How do I select a span containing a specific text value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint-2013

I want to find and replace the style of a span element.

I know how it's done in JQuery

```
$("span:contains('OVERVIEW')").text("OVERVIEW "+ localStorage.getItem("shape"));
```

what is the angular equivalent of the above?

Comment: Kindly read about [NgClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)  and [NgStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use ng-bind to achieve it. The following example code for your reference.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'OVERVIEW'+localStorage.getItem("shape");
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="bindExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <span ng-bind="name">OVERVIEW</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```